# conan2: Library 'X' not found in package (in "Testing the package" stage)

Tags: cmake, package-managers, conan, conan-2

I'm trying my luck with conan2, but I have a hard time getting it to build my library. Well to be precise, my library is packaged just fine, but the test_package invocation fails as it can't find said library. Here's the CMake error from the conan-generated `cmakedeps_macros.cmake`:

```
======== Testing the package: Building ========
cojson/0.1.0 (test package): Calling build()
cojson/0.1.0 (test package): Running CMake.configure()
cojson/0.1.0 (test package): RUN: cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="C:/dev/cojson/test_package/build/msvc-193-x86_64-20-release/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:/dev/cojson/test_package" -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091="NEW" "C:\dev\cojson\test_package"
...(cmake stuff)...
CMake Error at build/msvc-193-x86_64-20-release/generators/cmakedeps_macros.cmake:67 (message):
  Library 'cojson::cojson' not found in package.  If 'cojson::cojson' is a
  system library, declare it with 'cpp_info.system_libs' property
```

I'm not really adept enough to see behind the curtains. I have fairly good understanding of cmake, but I don't quite get how targets are imported into the test_package context. So I'm a bit lost with this error. Here is my project structure:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── main.cpp
├── include
│   └── cojson
│       └── myheader.hpp
├── tests
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── tests.cpp
├── test_package
│   ├── conanfile.py
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── src
│       └── example.cpp
└── LICENSE
```

I have gone through all tutorial examples (which of course work flawlessly) and poked around in the docs but I didn't find a specific hint on why the target might not be known. My guesses were

- target uses a different export name: Indeed the target is named cojson_core but I changed the export name to cojson like so:

  set_target_properties(cojson_core PROPERTIES EXPORT_NAME cojson)

so that should work or not?

Here are the relevant parts:

*conanfile.py (root):*

```
import os
from conan import ConanFile
from conan.tools.cmake import CMakeToolchain, CMake, cmake_layout
from conan.tools.build import check_min_cppstd
from conan.tools.files import copy

class cojsonConan(ConanFile):
    name = "cojson"
    version = "0.1.0"

    # Optional metadata
    license = "https://github.com/MartyMcFlyInTheSky/cojson/blob/master/LICENSE"
    author = "Samuel Beer"
    url = "https://github.com/MartyMcFlyInTheSky/cojson"
    description = "A C++ JSON library using coroutines"
    topics = ("json", "coroutines", "cpp20")

    # Binary configuration
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    options = {
        "shared": [True, False],
        "fPIC": [True, False],
    }
    default_options = {
        "shared": False,
        "fPIC": True,
    }

    # Sources located in same place
    exports = ["LICENSE"]
    exports_sources = "CMakeLists.txt", "src/*", "include/*", "tests/*"

    def validate(self):
        check_min_cppstd(self, "20")

    def config_options(self):
        if self.settings.os == "Windows":
            del self.options.fPIC

    def configure(self):
        # delete fPIC option if shared
        if self.options.shared:
            # If os=Windows, fPIC will have been removed in config_options()
            # use rm_safe to avoid double delete errors
            self.options.rm_safe("fPIC")

    def requirements(self):
        self.test_requires("gtest/1.14.0")

    def _configure_cmake(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        return cmake

    def layout(self):
        cmake_layout(self)

    def generate(self):
        tc = CMakeToolchain(self)
        tc.generate()

    def build(self):
        cmake = self._configure_cmake()
        cmake.build()
        # if not self.conf.get("tools.build:skip_test", default=False):
        cmake.test()

    def package(self):
        copy(self, "LICENSE", src=self.source_folder, dst=os.path.join(self.package_folder, "licenses"))
        cmake = self._configure_cmake()
        cmake.install()

    # consumer information
    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.libs = ["cojson"]
```

*conanfile.py (test_package):*

```
import os

from conan import ConanFile
from conan.tools.cmake import CMake, cmake_layout
from conan.tools.build import can_run

class cojsonConan(ConanFile):
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    generators = "CMakeDeps", "CMakeToolchain"

    def requirements(self):
        self.requires(self.tested_reference_str)

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()

    def layout(self):
        cmake_layout(self)

    def test(self):
        if can_run(self):
            cmd = os.path.join(self.cpp.build.bindir, "example")
            self.run(cmd, env="conanrun")
```

**EDIT1**:

@Tsyvarev in the comments had the notable idea to not export seperate target names. So what I did is I left my main target at cojson_core and aliased it to cojson::cojson_core for consistency, and adapted that in tests and test_package CMakeFiles:

*test_package/CMakeLists.txt*

```
...
target_link_libraries(example cojson::cojson_core)
...
```

In the conanfile I had to adapt the exported libraries as well:

*conanfile.py*

```
def package_info(self):
    # self.cpp_info.libs = ["cojson"]
    self.cpp_info.libs = ["cojson_core"]
    self.cpp_info.set_property("cmake_target_name", "cojson::cojson_core")
```

This got me at least one step further, as cojson::cojson_core seems to be found. HOWEVER: I get another error now, stating that it doesn't know where the lib header files are:

```
C:\dev\cojson\test_package\src\example.cpp(2,10): fatal  error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht geöffnet werden: "cojson/cojson.hpp": No such file or directory [C:\dev\cojson\test_package\build\msvc-193-x
86_64-20-release\example.vcxproj]
```

This is very confusing, given that the test_package obviously has found the cojson::cojson_core target which should declare the include directories. I went to test test_package with cmake alone and it works if I do it like this:

in `cojson/test_package/` execute

```
cmake -S . -B build -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\dev\installcojson
cmake --build build
```

The target is found so are the include directories. Idk why it doesn't work when conan is doing it. Any ideas? Maybe someone can explain how conan defines targets: Are these "wrapper" targets that conan defines by itself for every actual cmake target?

**EDIT2**:

The issue with the missing header file is now resolved. I had excluded the line

```
set_target_properties(cojson_core PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include/cojson/cojson.hpp;
)
```

for some reason. Inserting it back finally made me build the package. Still, the question is not resolved, as I want my target to have a different export name: cojson. I tried to again adapt the properties in *conanfile.py*

```
def package_info(self):
    # self.cpp_info.libs = ["cojson"]
    self.cpp_info.libs = ["cojson"]
    self.cpp_info.set_property("cmake_target_name", "cojson::cojson")
```

...aand the notorious error from above is back. How is the target not recognised?

Comment: Have you tried to test your package **without** changing the export name?

Comment: The ``def _configure_cmake(self):`` is not needed anymore with the new ``from conan.tools.cmake import CMake`` helper.

Comment: If the target name in the consumer side is different to the package name, you want the package to define in ``package_info()`` something like ``self.cpp_info.set_property("cmake_target_name", "myspecial::target_name")``. Maybe that is the issue?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Good idea see EDIT in OP

Comment: @drodri How do you mean that? _configure_cmake() is just a wrapper, is CMake().configure() not needed anymore at all? It doesn't do much more than that.

Comment: @drodri: I tried that thank you, and it got me a bit further but I'm still not there (see EDIT in OP)

Comment: I am not very familiar with Conan, but after reading its docs it seems that `CMakeDeps` generator is a **Conan** way to **generate config file**, which can be consumed by `find_package`. That generation is guided by properties you set in `package_info` method. **CMake** by itself is able to **generate config file** by means of `install(EXPORT)` comand. And exactly this command is affected by `EXPORT_NAME` property which you are trying to set. If your project generates the config file by itself, then just do **not use** CMakeDeps generator: allow `find_package` to find CMake-generated file.

Comment: Yes, the extra ``cmake.configure()`` before ``cmake.install()`` is no longer necessary, so the recipe can be simplified. Check the ``conan new cmake_lib -d name=pkg -d version=0.1`` in 2.0 and you will see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

The problem was that the conan toolchain will not only look for a config module, but also for the binary using `find_library()`

*test_package/build/msvc../generators/cmakedeps_macros.cmake:23*:

```
find_library(CONAN_FOUND_LIBRARY NAMES ${_LIBRARY_NAME} PATHS ${package_libdir}
             NO_DEFAULT_PATH NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH)
```

So it's important the binary name matches the library name of conanfile.py exactly.

### Solution

Add

```
set_target_properties(cojson_core PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "cojson")
```

to the target which corresponds to the library as defined in *conanfile.py*:

```
def package_info(self):
    self.cpp_info.libs = ["cojson"]
```